# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck to psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device: -71

Tags: boot, drivers, touchpad

Since this morning booting is stuck at  synaptics: Unable to query device: -71 error message. The laptop is a MSI Prestige 15 A12UC.

I noticed that when I press the power button, after having connected the docking station, it boots normally (and the touchpad works too).
The only change I did yesterday was to go in the driver section of the GUI Software Updates, and select the proprietary driver for the NVIDIA graphic card (tested one). This error seems to be related to the mouse/track-pad from what I read, so I don't know if it is related.
How to allow the laptop to boot normally without the docking station?